# Sorting by values in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to store FIFA Games, and set a scoreboard with a ranking system.

I shouldn't use logic in the view, but if I calculate them in the controller, it renders an error that the method user is not specified. When I put it in the loop, however, it recognizes it because the user is the looped item.

The app can already save games and calculate the winner. The app adds `winner_id` and `loser_id` to each game. Later in the scoreboard, I count how many current `user_id`'s from the loop match all games' `winner_id`'s and `loser_id`'s. This keeps the database clean. I don't want to keep the wins and losses in the db because when a game is deleted, it shouldn't count as a win or loss anymore.

Controller:

```
class ScoreboardController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.all
    end
end
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right:10px">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading">Scoreboard</div>

  <!-- Table -->
          <table class="table">
             <thead>
                 <th>#</th>
                 <th>Username</th>
                 <th>Ratio</th>
                 <th>Wins</th>
                 <th>Losses</th>
              </thead>

              <% @users.each do |user|%> 
                 <tbody> 

              <td>
               1 

              </td>

              <td>
                  <%= user.username %>
              </td>

                  <% if (Game.where(:winner_id => user.id).count) == 0 %>

                  <td>Unvalid</td>

                <% elsif (Game.where(:loser_id => user.id).count) == 0 %>

                     <td>Unvalid</td>

                     <% else %>   
                       <% @ratio =  (number_with_precision((((Game.where(:winner_id => user.id).count).to_f) / (Game.where(:loser_id => user.id).count).to_f), precision: 2))  %>

                     <td><%= @ratio %></td>


                     <% end %>

                <td>
                 <%= Game.where(:winner_id => user.id).count %>
              </td>
               <td>
                   <%= Game.where(:loser_id => user.id).count %>
              </td>


                     <% end %>
              </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
```

I'd like to put this list in the right order. The list should be ordered by ratio. => the @ratio from the view. Can I do this directly?

In the first `td`, the current position is shown. It shows `1` for every user. How can I make this `1`, `2`, `3`, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add those methods in your `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wins, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'winner_id'
  has_many :losses, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'loser_id'

  def ratio
    wins.count / losses.count.to_f * 100
  end
end
```

then in the controller :

```
def index
    @users = User.all.sort_by(&:ratio)
end
```

and in the view, use the user instance methods directly :
`<%= user.wins.count %>`

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing it the way @ThomasHaratyk has suggested above.

**Additional question:** in the first td the current position is shown, for now it shows a 1 for every user, how can I make this 1, 2 , 3 , ... ?

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, index|%> 
   <tbody> 
      <td>
          <%= index + 1 %>
       </td>
<% end %>
```